# How should I correctly request permission for my Facebook app?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've developed Facebook website application, which is using `user_likes` and `user_photos` permissions. I'm collecting informations who likes which photo and I'm generating list of users who is giving most likes, so user can check who likes his photos the most. And I have had one more app for generating list of with who is user chatting the most, but as I understood I cannot use it cause the permission associated with it is available on SSL sites only.

But I cannot find out why my request for `user_likes` and `user_photos` is still denied. I've tried like 4 times. And I was asking for more details. But it is like some robot is handling that, there is still just:

> This permission request doesn't meet our criteria for approval. Please only request permissions that you need to create a high quality, personalized in-app experience for people.

And thats it. I've read it and I'm using it the right way and I think that I don't violate any conditions. How can I know that if I develop an application that FB will not deny it even if it meets conditions of usage?

Do you have some experience in developing FB apps? Fxp. if you get some offer to make an FB app and you will do the app exactly like user expected, but FB will not approve it so the app is useless...

I'm in a worry because, I'd like offer that I can make FB apps as people want it.

Thanks for sharing your experience.

Comment: Did you check the list of 'Approved Items' in your developer console. If you  check the "Status & Review" section, you can see the list of approved items. If `user_likes` and `user_photos` is not in the list, you won't get the data. You can use Graph API Explorer to verify the permissions. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/

Comment: I know. I've requested these permission but they have not been approved. And I'm trying find out why and what should I do for getting them approved.

Comment: I've found that you often need to be extremely explicit about where each permission is used, why you need it, etc. in your request. Having a request with multiple paragraphs of text, each having 3~4 sentences, is not uncommon. Detailed, step by step explanations telling the reviewer where to click to test a specific permission and such seem to really help.

Comment: @JoryGeerts Yeah I've written like really detailed tutorial and I've even made a video-tutorial. I've explained, how do I use each permission as much as I could. And I was asking for a normal answer, it would be really helpful if they give me something what would tell me where is the problem, not just the robot static answer. I'll just keep trying, but it is really annoying how much time I've spent and I cannot get even normal answer.

Comment: Probably you can use this method:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/ - GET /{user-id}/photos/uploaded to get list of photo's uploaded.

And then use each object id and get list of likes to them:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/object/likes - /{object-id}/likes

Had used this in one of my client project and fb probably allowed. It was way back dont remember much tough.

Comment: @VivekSancheti I'm using it like this. And I'm generating a list of users with profile pictures, according to simillar likes. And I've described it in details and attached video-tutorial. And it has not been approved several times with no reason attached. Did you get approved for the first time? How does the output look in your app? Did you write something special to description?

Comment: @sczdavos We had used SSL server. Plus I wast not having access to their APi dashboard. Probably SSL server was the thing which helped us.

Probably you should try that. There are many free SSL certificate provider try once and check if they are still rejecting you.

Comment: @VivekSancheti I've found that there is explicitly written if the privilege requires SSL (fxp for ReadMessages) but it might be good idea I'll try it anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

user_photos is meant to be used in you application to pull photos from users profile, so you can use them in your app. Manipulate, or print them, or show some album, or whatever that brings new functionalities.

As I understood from your description - you want to pull photos just to get their likes. This data user already sees in Facebook. And that is in most cases the reason to bounce - as they do not see the extended experience.

Your app offers, as I understood, only statistics for Facebook.

It is worth to read those Common use cases described when submitting a request for a permission and validate if your use case is at least bit close to them.

Comment: I've also tried to get just the like persmission, but then it was difficult for me to get some list of users or activities so I've tried some other permission to do something simillar. But it was also rejected without given reason. I've read the use cases and I've decribed it all in detail with CAPS ask if they can tell me what is the problem. No answer at all. I'll try the SSL and I'll see. It is like guess what is wrong. Wait 5 days ohhh sorry you didn't guess it right, so now wait another 3 days until next submit and then another 5 days for review :D FB is awesome!

Comment: I've created FB for business and I've created some ticked. They check it out and approved it with appologies O.o